# Spring mvc calling get instead of set for setting request params- Is it a know issue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending post request to spring MVC controller. Request has parameter name buyDate and value is 05/01/2016.

My controller method is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/custInfo/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRequest(Customer customer, HttpSession session, 
    HttpServletRequest request) {}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true));
}
```

what I see after executing initBinder but before calling saveRequest method , spring specific  `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`   executing customer.getBuyDate()
method.

Per mine understanding only customer.setBuyDate() method should be called to set the parameter buyDate but why getBuyDate() is called here. Is it a bug here ? Is there a way to disable to execute getters (if possible for specific flow)?